# New line when using % formatting in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to print a new line while using % formatting. This is the code I have:

```
return '%s\n%s\n%s\nScore: %d' % (seqA, matches, seqB, score)
```

But that prints:

```
'ATTCGT\n||   |\nATCTAT\nScore: 2'
```

Is there a way to print new lines using this method?

Comment: You're confusing the diagnostics the Python shell prints (a representation, using the `repr` function, of the result of the previous line evaluated) with actual output of your script. Your code doesn't actually output anything.

Comment: I just tried it outside the Python IDLE program, and used 'print' and it worked. Sorry.

Comment: Don't be sorry, it's not an uncommon mistake.

Comment: The question is part of a pyschools challenge. 'Pairwise comparision of DNA sequences is a popular technique used in Bioinformatics. It usually involves some scoring scheme to express the degree of similarity. Write a function that compares two DNA sequences based on the following scoring scheme: +1 for a match, +3 for each consecutive match and -1 for each mismatch.' That's why I was using 'return'. I was struggling to get it right in their code editor so I tried IDLE. That was giving me the output in the OP, so I thought I was missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `print` instead of `return`. `print` evaluates each expression and writes the result to standard output, whereas `return` merely echoes the returned object (in IDLE):

```
>>> seqA = 'ATTCGT'
>>> matches = '||   |'
>>> seqB = 'ATCTAT'
>>> score = 2
>>> print '%s\n%s\n%s\nScore: %d' % (seqA, matches, seqB, score)
ATTCGT
||   |
ATCTAT
Score: 2
```

Comment: I feel like this answer is just inaccurate enough to be unhelpful, though it technically probably will solve his problem.

Comment: I've adjusted the answer to reflect more appropriate terminology. Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You get the value correctly. But you need the `print` it.